# Which numerical method is better for given ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given 
$$\dot{x}=-y$$
$$\dot{y}=x$$
$$x(0)=1, y(0)=2$$
Which numerical method you will prefer Backward Euler method or trapezoidal method.

Any hints how can i calculate the error and the cost of each method with a non-numerical way?

Comment: isn't the closed form solution just $x=C\sin t+D \cos t$?

Comment: yea actually  $$x=\sin t-2 \cos t$$

Comment: If you wanted to use a numerical method then a standard 4th order Runge-Kutta method will work on many problems. If you use Matlab, there is a list of numerical methods (ode23, ode45, ode113, ode15s, ode23s, ode23t, ode23tb) which deal with specific types of problems. There are also spectral element methods. Are you interested in comparing the error with the exact solution? The last sentence of your question isn't clear to me.

Comment: my question is how you can find the error, and the time cos for each method with out using computer